# sass error: No such file or directory

Tags: css, sass, compiler-errors

Sass is throwing an error on multiple projects on both of my computers when I try to compile the scss files to css. I'm using dart-sass. I'm typing the command in the terminal from the root of the projects and the file path is correct. I've tried both

`sass --watch src/styles/scss:src/styles/css`

and also just

`sass src/styles/scss:src/styles/css`

but the results are the same:

> Error reading src/styles/scss:src/styles/css: no such file or directory.

As such I can't compile any of my style files.

Comment: Did you try with ./src ?

Comment: Yes, it gives me the same result, telling me that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: According to http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html
you should use:
sass --watch src/styles/sass:src/styles/css
where styles is a folder containing multiple sass files

Comment: @OleksandrOleksiv I changed my folder name and ran that, still telling me there is no such file or directory. But I've used it in multiple projects in the past with a folder called 'scss' and it worked fine. It just stopped working this week out of the blue.

Answer (score 1):

**filename is required to select directory**

---

Try this  sass --watch src/styles/scss/fileName.scss:src/styles/css

Comment: That doesn't work either unfortunately. inside my styles folder, I have two folders other folders: scss and css. It should compile all of the files inside the scss folder with the commands I used above but it isn't. I've tried testing it on single files but that isn't working either.

Comment: Try open terminal from folder solution as administrator . And to select all scss files write after select folder *.scss

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out a solution if anyone else runs into this problem. You should uninstall dart sass from your computer(prefix this command with sudo if using mac):

> `npm uninstall sass -g`

Then, install a stable version of ruby sass:

> `gem install sass`

Now you should be able to run `sass --watch src/styles/scss:src/styles/css` and it will compile.

Note: If you were to do `npm install sass` that would install the latest version written in dart, which is what seems to have caused my problems.

Comment: Using Sublime text simply uninstalling the npm version and installing the gem version got things working for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, I had to make my way to the file location and then run the command. Example:

Project Structure:

```
src
   abc
      prq
         main.html
         main.scss
```

When I launch the terminal, it defaults to `src` folder

```
PS C:\Users\src> sass --watch main.scss:main.css
```

Running command here will throw error:

> Error reading main.scss: no such file or directory.

Now, browsing to `prq` directory & running command, will be successful.

```
PS C:\Users\src\abc\pqr> sass --watch main.scss:main.css
```

> Compiled main.scss to main.css.
> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.